# How can I pass a date type input from an HTML form into an express variable?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am using the express-node.js backend to handle an HTML form. While I am able to pass text inputs just fine using body-parser, I am having trouble passing different types of HTML data, specifically dates.

I have tried using the new Date() function to process the data. While that works for grabbing the current date in javascript, I couldn't make it handle inputted dates.

HTML:

```
<form action="/business" method="post">
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEstDate" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Express:

```
app.post("/business", function(req, res){
var estDate = new Date((req.inputEstDate).toISOstring());
console.log(estDate)
})
```

I'd like the date that the user inputted to show in the console log but so far I have gotten errors ranging from 'undefined' variable to undefined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date you've sent to the server does indeed reside at `req.inputEstDate`, then I would say that your order of operations here is incorrect. You are calling `Date#toIsoString` on a string. Try doing `new Date(req.inputEstDate).toISOString()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have retyped it in your synax but now have the error "Invalid Date". On the front end the date form shows up as 'mm/dd/yyyy' how can I specify a valid date entry?

Comment: I would log the raw input to the console and ensure that that is actually where the date is being put on the request object, because JS's `Date` can handle dates of that format. I suspect the `inputEstDate` isn't where you expect it is.

Comment: The `body-parser` docs imply that it should be located at `req.body`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: I have tried including req.body but it was the same result of "Invalid Date", my assumption was that body-parser was only for text data types. Additionally the console output was:
 console.log(document.getElementById('inputEstDate').value) =>
2019-01-01
undefined

Comment: I meant try logging `req.body` to the console on the server to see what properties are present. I am assuming that the `inputEstDate` will be in the `req.body`.

Comment: OMG I found the bug!! I have been using HTML 'id' to pass variables when 'name' is what worked on the other pages.  Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!